# How to get unchecked checkbox value.? with Id condition.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

Actually I am trying to get all unchecked checkbox value but where title = 1 condition..please help.my jquery code is.

```
var uncheckedValues = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="ing[]"][title= "1"]:not(:checked)').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

and my checkbox code is

```
 <input class="badgebox" type="checkbox" onClick="addprice(<?php echo $total; ?>,<?php echo $addingri->id; ?>,'<?php echo $pprod_material->name; ?>')" id="<?php echo $addingri->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $pprod_material->id; ?>*<?php echo $addingri->price; ?>*<?php echo $addingri->name; ?>" name="ing[]" <?php if($pprod_material->id == 1) {  echo "checked";} ?>  title="<?php echo $pprod_material->id; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("input[type='checkbox'][name='ing[]'][title= '1']:not(:checked)")` selector to get all the unchecked checkbox having `title="1"`.

Please check below working snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //On page load
  uncheckedChk();

  //on checkbox change
  $("input[type='checkbox'][name='ing[]'][title= '1']").on("change",function(){
    uncheckedChk();
  });
});

//Function to identify all the unchecked checkbox with title=1
function uncheckedChk(){
  var not_checked = []
  $("input[type='checkbox'][name='ing[]'][title= '1']:not(:checked)").each(function (){
    not_checked.push($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(not_checked);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="ing[]" value="check-1" title="1" checked><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="ing[]" value="check-2" title="1" checked><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="ing[]" value="check-2" title="1" ><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="ing[]" value="check-3" title="1"><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="ing[]" value="check-4" title="2" ><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="ing[]" value="check-5" title="1" ><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not include unchecked selector that's why we have to invert the :checked selector:

Something like.

`$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")`